# Help with Mazda 323F

Tags: mazda, mazda-323f

I'm looking forward into buying one. Found that year of make was 1997 meaning it has an ODB II connector which is not the standard type. I show in another post a connection scheme of a standard OBD connector with a Mazda Lantis.  Is it the same for the 323F?

Apart from the above, is it a safe car? Problem free?
Thx

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The safety of a car is largely controlled by the skill of the driver....

Comment: The ODB connector has nothing to do with a car being safe or not. If you want safety measurements, check out rating organisations like https://www.euroncap.com/en